# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() error

Tags: php, mysql, database, error-handling

So I've been looking in the forums, but didn't find anything that helped me!
Here is the full code. The error occurs at $result = $conn->query($query);
I'am new to php so go easy on me, lol.

```
<?php
include 'Register.html';
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    SignUp();
}
global $conn;
$servername = "localhost";
$username1 = "root";
$password1 = "";
$dbname = "fiesta_db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username1, $password1, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    return $conn;
}

function NewUser()
{
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];


  $register = "INSERT INTO website (username, email, password)
  VALUES ($username, $email, $password)";

  if ($conn->query($register) == TRUE) {
    echo "Successfully registered.";
  }
  else {
    echo "Wrong syntax";
  }
}
function SignUp()
{
  if(!empty($_POST['username']))
  {
    global $conn;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM website WHERE username ='$_POST[username]' AND email ='$_POST[email]'; ";
    $result = $conn->query($query);


    if ($result->num_rows != 0)
    {
      NewUser();
    }
    else {
      echo "Username or Email already exist!";
    }
  }
  $conn->close();
}
?>
```

Hope you guys can help (Totally not just trying to add more details)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sign-Up</title>
</head>
<body id="body-color">
<div id="Sign-Up">
<form action='register_do.php' method='post'
    accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset >
<legend>Register</legend>
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<label for='username' >Username:</label>
<input type='text' name='username' id='username' maxlength="50" />
<label for='email' >Email Address:</label>
<input type='text' name='email' id='email' maxlength="50" />
<label for='password' >Password:</label>
<input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />

</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the register page, I do not have anymore code to show this is everything.
Bump

Comment: What's the *exact* error and on what *exact* line does it happen?  If the error is telling you that `$conn` was never initialized then, well, where do you initialize it?  Nowhere in this code.  (It's also worth noting that when you *do* get this to work you're going to have a glaring SQL injection vulnerability.)

Comment: This is not the full code, I'am new to php also..

Comment: @Fred-ii- Obviously the question is incomplete. But even the little bit of error message he gives makes it clear that the problem is with the value of `$conn`. You just reflexively noticed the "Call to method" error without looking at the specific method name, and assumed it's the same problem we see 99% of the time.

Comment: Post your full code, complete with the class(es)/function(s) and the HTML form for this.

Comment: @Musti: `$conn` is either never being initialized, or its initialization is failing with an error.  You're going to have to investigate further, as both possibilities are outside any of the code shown.  Look for where you try to initialize that variable, check for errors from the database API, turn on error reporting, check the PHP logs, etc.

Comment: actually, I'm betting on variable scoping, since they global declaration only kicks in if this succeeds `if(!empty($_POST['username']))`.

Comment: `VALUES ($username, $email, $password)` @Barmar see? that failed them; knew it. That being part of many errors.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Except the error is in `SignUp`, not `Login`.

Comment: @Musti, what is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `SignUp()` before you assign to `$conn` in the main code. Move that code down.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username1 = "root";
$password1 = "";
$dbname = "fiesta_db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username1, $password1, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    return $conn;
}

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    SignUp();
}
```

You also don't need the `global $conn;` statement in the main code. Variables assigned outside of a function are automatically global, you only need the statement inside a function to allow it to access the global variable.

You're also missing quotes in the query in `NewUser()`:

```
$register = "INSERT INTO website (username, email, password)
    VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";
```

And in `SignUp()`, you're using the wrong condition. If the username is available, the `SELECT` query will return `0` rows, so it should be:

```
if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
    NewUser();
} else {
    echo "Username or Email already exist!";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now is just keeps telling me the user already exists, even if it doesnt.

Comment: Try echoing the query and running it by hand, to see what it's returning.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Put `echo $query;` in the script, then copy the query to whatever program you use to perform queries by hand, such as PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: Here is how the query looks SELECT * FROM website WHERE username ='da' AND email ='da'

Comment: That looks fine. What happens when you run the query?

Comment: If I run inside phpmyadmin in my db it doesnt show any problem.

Comment: Who said there was a problem? The question is whether it returns any matching rows.

Comment: Doesnt return any rows, there is no rows in the db.

Comment: Your condition is backwards. You want to call `NewUser()` when it returns zero rows, not when it returns more than zero rows. it should be `if ($result->num_rows == 0)`

Comment: BTW, your code will allow the same username to be registered with different emails. Is that what you really want?

Comment: Yeah I figured that out :P there were also some errors in the NewUser but by adding global $conn it fixed it and ty! Btw do you have a skype I can add you on?

Comment: Nope I do not want that lol also this is just a test register page.

Comment: Then remove `AND email = '$_POST[email]` from the query.

Comment: Okay thank you! So do you have a skype I can contact you on?

Comment: No, I don't want direct contact from SO users.